# I want to add icons of excel to export data from report in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

this code is for model

```
if($this ->request-> getpost('export_excel')) {
        //echo "string";exit();
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Indicators Detail Data Report .xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
}

$result['exportIcons']=exportIcons($_REQUEST);
    return $result;`
```

when i click on the icon it reloads my web URL and Error 404 File not found occurs

Comment: You need to provide further information. We don't even know what you're trying to achieve here and what you did.

Comment: this is controller code and i have made a function in helpers `$data['exportIcons'] = exportIcons($_REQUEST);`

Comment: this is the code that i made a function in helpers for excel export
`if($excelonly==NULL){
    $finalString .= 
   '<input type="hidden" name="export_excel" value="export_excel" />
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-right: 47px; margin-top: 11px;">
      <img class="handland" id="vampire" data-original-title="View in Excel" onclick="document.getElementById(\'export-form\').submit()" src="'.base_url().'/assets/img/excel.png" style="height:32px;margin-right:-105px;" alt="img-excel" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Excel" data-placement="bottom" />
</div>';
}`